# Cannot GET / using node.js + socket.io to connect client to server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So I am trying to create an indoor location tracker using Bluetooth using the software's node.js and socket.io. I am using a raspberry pi 3 to pickup the RSSI readings and just want the RSSI value from one specific hardware. I have been able to create a connection between my client and server and managed to get the uuid for the specific hardware I want the RSSI value of. However while the connection has been successful I am not getting any of the RSSI values from the pi. Every time I execute the codes below all I get is "Cannot GET / " error whenever I visit my localhost web page.

The following code is what I executed from the pi:

```
var noble = require('noble');

//replace localhost with your server's IP;
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost/scanner');

//replace with your hardware address
var addressToTrack = '7c669d9b2dda'; 

socket.on('connect', function(){  
  console.log('connected to server');
});

noble.on('discover', function(peripheral){
  if(peripheral.uuid == addressToTrack){
    socket.emit('deviceData', {mac: peripheral.uuid, rssi:peripheral.rssi});    
  }
});

noble.startScanning([], true)
```

This next code is the code I used to setup my server and how it should receive the information sent from the pi:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var scanner = io.of('/scanner'); 

scanner.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log('Scanner Connected');

    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
        //received message from scanner
        //do some processing here
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('Scanner Disconnected');
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

The following code is taken from https://blog.truthlabs.com/beacon-tracking-with-node-js-and-raspberry-pi-794afa880318 if you're wondering where I am referencing the code from.

I am new to all this so I am trying to understand where the problem is occuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any express route setup for `/` that's why you're getting: `Cannot GET /`

Add:

```
// this should be AFTER socket.io server setup
app.use((req, res) => {
   res.send('Hello world');
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Now every endpoint but `socket-io` specific endpoints will respond with: `hello world`

---

Aside from that, regarding your client side code. You're trying to connect to: `http://localhost` instead of `http://localhost:3000` which the port where your socket.io server is running.

Comment: Thank you for the help. What you said worked and I managed to get 'Hello World' to show on my localhost web page. But I don't understand why the rssi values from my pi isn't showing on the server if the connection has been made.

Comment: Check updated answer, you're using wrong URL on the client.

Comment: so I found that I had to put the IP address of the server and the port number and it shows that a connection has been made between my pi and the server. But that's its no rssi values are showing up.

Comment: That's a complete different question. This answer solves the original question. You can always mark it as the accepted answer, and create a new one, I'll be happy to help you with other problems with your code.

Comment: Sorry new to this. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: You can post the new question in the comments, and I'll take a look :). No worries you're welcome!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61409653/not-understanding-why-i-am-not-receiving-any-rssi-data-from-my-raspberry-pi-3-to hopefully I am doing this correctly