# Not understanding why I am not receiving any rssi data from my raspberry pi 3 to my server

Tags: node.js, socket.io, raspberry-pi3, rssi

I am having problems trying to display the RSSI values from my raspberry pi 3 to show on my server. 
[Connection Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmwe3.png) as you can see by the picture I have been able to successfully connect my client and server but no rssi data are showing.

The following code is what I executed from the pi:

```
var noble = require('noble');

//replace localhost with your server's IP;
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:3000/scanner');

//replace with your hardware address
var addressToTrack = '7c669d9b2dda'; 

socket.on('connect', function(){  
  console.log('connected to server');
});

noble.on('discover', function(peripheral){
  if(peripheral.uuid == addressToTrack){
    socket.emit('deviceData', {mac: peripheral.uuid, rssi:peripheral.rssi});    
  }
});

noble.startScanning([], true)
```

This next code is the code I used to setup my server and how it should receive the information sent from the pi:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var scanner = io.of('/scanner'); 

scanner.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log('Scanner Connected');

    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
        //received message from scanner
        //do some processing here
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('Scanner Disconnected');
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

The following code is taken from https://blog.truthlabs.com/beacon-tracking-with-node-js-and-raspberry-pi-794afa880318 if you're wondering where I am referencing the code from.

I am new to all this so forgive if I continuously ask for clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a listener for `deviceData` on the server, which is the event you're emitting from the client.

```
socket.on('deviceData', function(msg) {
    //received message from scanner
    //do some processing here
});
```

Comment: can you give me an example for e.g. a website I can reference to because I'm not understanding what I would need to do with that particular section of the code.

Comment: You're doing: noble.on('discover', function(peripheral){
  if(peripheral.uuid == addressToTrack){
    socket.emit('deviceData', {mac: peripheral.uuid, rssi:peripheral.rssi});    
  }
});

on the client side. You have to listn to `deviceData` on the server.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I managed to find the code I needed and finally got the RSSI values showing on my command line.